# Url ending in :82 laravel 3

Tags: url, laravel, laravel-3

i made a website in laraver 3 a year ago, now i am trying to move it to another host but i am having a problem with the

```
URL::base()
```

Its giving a :82 at end of the url, for example my domain is www.Domain.com and when i try to redirect to a route it makes a link to www.Domain.com:82/route

Please help i dont have idea of what its the problem.

I think its the .htaccess but its :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I donpt see problem with it

Comment: What does your `/application/application.php` look like? Check the Application Index portion.